# How can I make my own buttons look and behave exactly like the ones created by jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created some widgets with jQuery UI and I notice that buttons have a distinct look and feel (colors, hover effects, etc.)

But it seems I cannot recreate the same with my own buttons. I duplicated the code, but I'm still getting different colors and no hover effects, so I assume that some of the visuals are done with JavaScript events.

Is there any way to make my own buttons look and behave like the jQuery ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [this article](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/) about styling buttons using the jQuery UI CSS framework.  I found it handy when I had to whip up some buttons awhile ago.

It has details about hovering, disabling, setting priority, toolbars, etc. with buttons.